# Does typekit allow using @font-face?

Tags: css, typekit

I want to use the font from typekit website for my blog. As far as I'm using now is have the javascript on the head tag, and load the font using the launch the kit option from typekit.

My question is, Does typekit allow adding fonts with CSS using @font-face?

Answer (score 6):

Not for embedding, but you can still specify Typekit-loaded fonts directly in your stylesheet. Typekit purposefully doesn't allow direct links to font outline files (otf, sag, etc.) for the sake of licensing, but they've added the ability to let you specify font-families via CSS.

From the kit view, click on "Using weights & styles in CSS" to get a list of exactly which font-family names (and recommended fallbacks) you can use in your stylesheet.

Source/More Info: http://blog.typekit.com/2011/06/29/using-typekit-fonts-in-your-own-css/

Comment: Bummer. If I could cache the css, I won't have to decided whether to have the page load wait on the typekit script or have my fonts blink when they're loaded because they don't cache very well. Too bad not everybody can run like Google Fonts

Answer (score 0):

This is possible now as an early access feature:

[css-font-loading](https://blog.typekit.com/2017/08/30/css-font-loading/)